# .how to find service URl in wso2 data service

Tags: wso2

I created a data service using below url

[Data Service](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/RDBMS)

anyway i need to know how to find my service url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you successfully create a Data Service, it will be listed under services.

Look at the final step in the same [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/RDBMS) you have referred.

Access the WSDLs and see whether your operations are defined properly.

You should be able to see the service endpoint url in the WSDL.

You can just invoke the web service from your own client. You can also try soapUI as a testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Service Dashboard and there you can find the service Endpoints. To view the Service Dashboard of a service, just click on the dataservice you created which is available in the services list.

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/Service+Dashboard