# How to test a deployed service endpoint?

Tags: wso2

I created a simple data service using the [Example](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/RDBMS).
The service dashboard give URLs below:

Endpoints

- https://192.168.x.x:9443/services/DataServiceSamples1/
- http://192.168.x.x:9763/services/DataServiceSamples1/
- local:///services/DataServiceSamples1/

But when I try to use them, I get the following error.

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/DataServiceSamples1/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

I tried to replace the **192.168.1.2** with **localhost** but I got the same result.

---

```
http ://192 .168.1.2:9763/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . SOAP11Endpoint
https ://192 .168.1.2:9443/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . SecureSOAP11Endpoint
https ://192 .168.1.2:9443/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . SecureSOAP12Endpoint
http ://192 .168.1.2:9763/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . SOAP12Endpoint
http ://192 .168.1.2:9763/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . HTTPEndpoint
https ://192 .168.1.2:9443/services/ DataServiceSamples1 . SecureHTTPEndpoint
```

Above is the part of my wsdl file.So why it gives me several endpoints?
how to test these url's working fine.anyway i test he service using using Soapui.it's working fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.how to find service URl in wso2 data service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626846/how-to-find-service-url-in-wso2-data-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify whether the service endpoint exists by calling its wsdl file from the browser. In order to do this goto /repository/conf/carbon.xml file and change the following entry as this.

```
<!-- If this parameter is set, the ?wsdl on an admin service will not give the admin service wsdl. -->
    <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

After that go to your browser and enter https://192.168.x.x:9443/services/DataServiceSamples1?wsdl. If you see the wsdl file here it means you service is deployed and running. You can send a request to the endpoint from SoapUI or some other client then. If you don't see the WSDL, there is some error in your service and haven't been deployed correctly.

Comment: The parameter mentioned in this answer is only applicable Admin Services, right? And Data Service is not an admin service, is it?

Comment: I tried this with using WSO2 ESB and I was able to get deployed proxy services wsdls with this too. Therefore it seems this configuration works for the deployed services as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is nothing with the endpoint URI or etc. But you need the WS action to be set properly to hit your DS.

Can you share us or check on your ESB config in which you call this DSS endpoint, whether you set the WS action to the operation name of your DS to which you want to call. 
You MUST have the payload correctly. Please use DSS try it tool/DSS WSDL to verify the payload

i.e